# Why wont my input boxplot code not work for my matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, matrix

I am having issues getting a plot for my dataframe. Attached below is my sample matrix dataframe. This class is confirmed a dataframe.

[Dataframe (10 rows, 59 columns originally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l5Zf.png)

I have originally tried to create a plot using facet_grid, with poor results.
(Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `x`.

- Plot is missing `x`
- Layer 1 is missing `x`)

Instead, I decided to simplify it and create a box plot with everything on 1 graph. However, my graph looked like this:
[ugly graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3trFn.png)

My simple plot code is below; does anyone know why things are plotted poorly? Any insight is helpful. This is my first post, so I hope things are formatted correctly.

`ggplot(newdf, aes(x, y, fill = x))+ geom_boxplot()`

The end goal would be a boxplot shown for each gene with the observations of the individuals within each box. I am following this example:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ncnv.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  To help us to help you would you mind sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when following examples you should make sure to change the variable's names in them to *your* variable's names.

In `ggplot(newdf, aes(x, y, fill = x))+ geom_boxplot()`, the errors probably come from the fact that you have neither an x or y column in newdf.
Or if you do, they aren't what you need for your goal.

The end goal being

> a boxplot shown for *each gene* with the *observations of the individuals* within each box

your x variabe needs to be a column in which you have the genes names and y a column with the value of the observation for these gene.

In other word, you need to reformat your data.frame into a long format (right now you have what's called a wide format).

There many ways to do so, a simple one with base R is to repeat the name of each column times the number of row for the gene column and then unlisting your data.frame into the value column like so :

```
# needed a a data.frame so made a fake one to illustrate :
newdf <- data.frame(gene1 = runif(10, ), gene2 = runif(10), gene3 = runif(10))
# this convert your data.frame from wide to long
newdf.long <- data.frame(
  gene = rep(names(newdf), each=nrow(newdf)), 
  value = unlist(newdf), 
  row.names = NULL
)
```

Then, you need to make sure to use the right variable's name when building your ggplot :

```
ggplot(newdf.long, aes(x = gene, y = value, fill = gene)) + geom_boxplot()
```